# Scilab-mode syntax highlighting

Tags: syntax-highlighting

I'm trying to install (and run) `scilab-mode`, but the syntax highlighting does not work when I open `.sci` or `.sce` file.

I use the exact configuration described in the scilab.el package.

https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/scilab.el

Any help?

Comment: With so few details about what you've done, it will likely take psychic powers to figure out the solution.

Comment: For the beginning you can reduce your setup to `(defvar default-fill-column (default-value 'fill-column)) (autoload 'scilab-mode "scilab") (add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.\\(sci\\|sce\\)\\'" . scilab-mode))`. Try that and report whether `scilab-mode` works for you afterwards. Note, that this does not include `scilab-shell` yet.

Comment: Note that posting: https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2018-01/msg00542.html about `default-fill-column`.

Comment: Note that the above setup does not include `scilab-shell` yet. For `scilab-shell` to work you have to setup `scilab-shell-command`, e.g. by `(defvar scilab-shell-command) (setq scilab-shell-command "scilab-adv-cli") (autoload 'scilab-shell "scilab")`. But, they removed `scilex` from `scilab`. So I do not know whether `scilab-shell` will work as expected for you. (Note, that I do not use `scilab` anymore so much. I use `octave` instead because of Cygwin support and Matlab compatibility.)

Answer (score 0):

[The help page](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ScilabMode) clearly says that this is an old script which does not work with the current version of Emacs without adapting it. It's really a shame and I would also be interested, but this elisp script is simply orphaned.

Comment: It's probably quite easy to update the package.  I'd have done it already if the copyright paperwork allowed it to be included in GNU ELPA.  But I can't even find a currently valid email for its author Alexander Vigodner :-(